# ASP.NET Entity Manager: create more than one entity in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to to create a create-view where you have the possibility to enter a value for more than one entity - "a list of entities"
e.g. Entity Class

```
public class MyEntity{
public string myAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

For the View I created a ModelView which looks like this:

```
public class MoreEntites{
public List<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}
```

In the View I want to use MoreEntities to give the user the possibility to enter more datasets than one in just one view (my suggestions which doesnt work of course)

```
@model myproject.ViewModels.MoreEntities
 ...
<div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyEntities.ElementAt(0).MyAttribute)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyEntities.ElementAt(0).MyAttribute)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyEntities.ElementAt(0).MyAttribute)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyEntities.ElementAt(1).MyAttribute)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyEntities.ElementAt(1).MyAttribute)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyEntities.ElementAt(1).MyAttribute)
</div>
...
```

Now in the controller I want to iterate over the list and write every item of MyEntities in the database. When I run the programm I get an exception that my List is null and I should check it for null before I use it.
Is this possible and how does it work? One "Solution" would be to create an Array but in this case my program would be scalable.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you include your controller method code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating a list of objects in mvc4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823604/updating-a-list-of-objects-in-mvc4)

Comment: Doesn't work because List<Entity> is not a list of instances at this time, if you want to update it is

Answer (score 0):

Works with Array[] of Entity!!!!
Solution:
Model:

```
public class MyEntity{
public string MyAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MoreEntites{
public MyEntity[] MyEntities { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model myproject.ViewModels.MoreEntities
 ...
<div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyEntities[0].MyAttribute)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyEntities.[0].MyAttribute)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyEntities[0].MyAttribute)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyEntities[1].MyAttribute)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyEntities[1].MyAttribute)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyEntities[1].MyAttribute)
</div>
...
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateMoreEntitiesAtOnce(MoreEntities set)
{
    foreach(var item in set.MyEntities) 
    {
        db.MyEntity.Add(item);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

in my case if have to try if its possible to add more TextBoxes to the View by JavaScript
Therefore you need to increment the name of the textboxes in plain html when adding them to the DOM

Comment: `CreateMoreEntitiesAtOnce(MyEntities set)` <-- whats `MyEntities` here? and `Choice[]` ?

Comment: just a relict of my original code, sorry
replaced it with MyEntities